# Add extra parameter to URL with GET form

Tags: php, javascript, forms, parameters, get

I use a form with GET method to add parameter to my url.
However I have a problem.

I use different forms to put different parameters in the URL.
But when I select the first one, and it is in the URL, and I select another one, the first one goes away.

How do I solve this?

```
<form action="" method="GET">
<select name="course" data-placeholder="Kies een vak..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                                  <option value=""></option> 
                                  <option value="0">Alles</option> 
                                  <option value="1">Markten & Prijzen</option> 
                                  <option value="2">Wiskunde</option> 
                                  <option value="3">Marketing</option> 
</select>   
</form>

<form action="" method="GET">
<select name="price" data-placeholder="Prijscategorie..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                                  <option value=""></option> 
                                  <option value="0">Alles</option> 
                                  <option value="2">< 2 euro</option> 
                                  <option value="4">< 4 euro</option> 
                                  <option value="6">< 6 euro</option> 
                                  <option value="8">< 8 euro</option> 
                                  <option value="10">< 10 euro</option> 
</select>   
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the forms and replace the onchange with a submit button:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="course" data-placeholder="Kies een vak..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">Alles</option>
        <option value="1">Markten & Prijzen</option>
        <option value="2">Wiskunde</option>
        <option value="3">Marketing</option>
    </select>
    <select name="price" data-placeholder="Prijscategorie..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0">Alles</option>
        <option value="2">< 2 euro</option>
        <option value="4">< 4 euro</option>
        <option value="6">< 6 euro</option>
        <option value="8">< 8 euro</option>
        <option value="10">< 10 euro</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

If you want the onchange you can do this:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="course" data-placeholder="Kies een vak..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0" <?php if($_GET[course] == '0'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Alles</option>
        <option value="1" <?php if($_GET[course] == '1'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Markten & Prijzen</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($_GET[course] == '2'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Wiskunde</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($_GET[course] == '3'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Marketing</option>
    </select>
    <select name="price" data-placeholder="Prijscategorie..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="0" <?php if($_GET[price] == '0'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>Alles</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($_GET[price] == '2'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>< 2 euro</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($_GET[price] == '4'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>< 4 euro</option>
        <option value="6" <?php if($_GET[price] == '6'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>< 6 euro</option>
        <option value="8" <?php if($_GET[price] == '8'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>< 8 euro</option>
        <option value="10" <?php if($_GET[price] == '10'){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>< 10 euro</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are able to keep them as two separate forms but set attribute id for each one (unique id for each one of course) and the onchange event should trigger a function that do submitting.

```
<form action="" method="GET" id="firstF">
<select name="course" data-placeholder="Kies een vak..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" onchange="doSubmit('firstF')">
                                  <option value=""></option> 
                                  <option value="0">Alles</option> 
                                  <option value="1">Markten & Prijzen</option> 
                                  <option value="2">Wiskunde</option> 
                                  <option value="3">Marketing</option> 
</select>   
</form>

<form action="" method="GET" id="secondF">
<select name="price" data-placeholder="Prijscategorie..." class="chzn-select" tabindex="2" onchange="doSubmit('secondF')">
                                  <option value=""></option> 
                                  <option value="0">Alles</option> 
                                  <option value="2">< 2 euro</option> 
                                  <option value="4">< 4 euro</option> 
                                  <option value="6">< 6 euro</option> 
                                  <option value="8">< 8 euro</option> 
                                  <option value="10">< 10 euro</option> 
</select>   
</form>
```

And then write the JavaScript function as follows:

```
 <script>
    function doSubmit(id){
    f = document.getElementById(id);
    f.submit();
    }

</script>
```

The following is a live demo, http://jsfiddle.net/JkrCu/

**This is updated demo to stop submitting if the select is changed to an empty value, i.e the initial item in the list (the blank item)**   http://jsfiddle.net/JkrCu/1/